Getting a 403 error when pinging Elasticsearch in Golang
I'm working on a project using Golang and Elasticsearch. I set up my Elasticsearch client in the Golang service with the olivere/elastic/v7 package. When I tried to ping Elasticsearch using client.Ping(url).Do(ctx), I got a 403 error. What permissions does this user need to be able to ping Elasticsearch?
I have two users: one is a reader and the other is an updater. My reader can ping the server, but the updater can't.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
